# How to fix corrupted file on git-lfs server (gitlab)?

Tags: git, gitlab, corruption, git-lfs

We are using GitLab 11.2.1-ee with git-lfs (v.2.4.2) enabled.
We found that we have corrupted object in git-lfs on server. When we run

```
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:lfs:check VERBOSE=1
```

, we have

```
- 1401..1600: Failures: 1
  - LFS object: b675b00828707cd53dc5c130efce8a9d352e5efd8b9b29f06808810b6ebb5491: Checksum mismatch
```

Now when we try to do 
`git lfs pull` in clones, we got

```
Expected OID b675b00828707cd53dc5c130efce8a9d352e5efd8b9b29f06808810b6ebb5491, got 2c6abc2c4d29bd1c7f0041160ea15ea2765df10194a6e9ef3e6e2139c11fc67f after 12427595 bytes written
error: failed to fetch some objects from 'https://192.168.1.100/root/our_project.git/info/lfs'
```

How should we fix this corruption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

We found that sha256sum of contents of file `b6/75/b00828707cd53dc5c130efce8a9d352e5efd8b9b29f06808810b6ebb5491` on server equals to `2c6abc2c4d29bd1c7f0041160ea15ea2765df10194a6e9ef3e6e2139c11fc67f` (which seems to be incorrect), and contents of same file on repo clone is correct (equals to `b675b00828707cd53dc5c130efce8a9d352e5efd8b9b29f06808810b6ebb5491`).
We replaced contents of file `b6/75/b00828707cd53dc5c130efce8a9d352e5efd8b9b29f06808810b6ebb5491` on server with contents of this file from repo clone, and all is ok now.
We can do pull and push and change branches in new clones now without any errors.

To get sha256 on xubuntu we used

```
cat b6/75/b00828707cd53dc5c130efce8a9d352e5efd8b9b29f06808810b6ebb5491 | sha256sum
```

And on mac:

```
shasum -a 256 b6/75/b675b00828707cd53dc5c130efce8a9d352e5efd8b9b29f06808810b6ebb5491
```